# Listing most recent ZFS snapshots

Tags: linux, list, search, snapshot, zfs

I am regularly taking ZFS snapshots for 30 Virtual Machines (VMs) for 20 versioning of times.

My list of snapshots is for only two VMs:

```
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-14_20:08:20   218M      -  80.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-15_00:13:27  46.4M      -  80.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-15_04:23:47  20.6M      -  80.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-15_08:11:11  53.3M      -  80.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-15_11:12:03   181M      -  80.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-15_14:12:32   176M      -  80.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-15_17:12:09   126M      -  80.5G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-15_20:11:06   120M      -  80.5G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-16_05:29:05   157M      -  80.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-16_11:27:24  6.72M      -  80.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-16_11:28:08  6.75M      -  80.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-16_14:07:33   208M      -  80.5G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-16_17:08:18   142M      -  80.4G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-16_20:05:09  55.3M      -  80.4G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-17_00:08:29  53.7M      -  80.4G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-17_04:07:15  46.3M      -  80.4G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-17_08:06:04  53.9M      -  80.4G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-17_11:05:05   209M      -  80.3G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-17_14:15:43   202M      -  80.3G  -
rpool/data/vm-100-disk-1@rep_100_2018-08-17_17:20:43     0B      -  80.2G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-14_20:06:09   588M      -  75.5G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-15_00:06:33   106M      -  75.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-15_04:11:10  65.2M      -  75.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-15_08:06:22  60.6M      -  75.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-15_11:07:57  56.8M      -  75.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-15_14:08:06  58.4M      -  75.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-15_17:08:28  61.0M      -  75.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-15_20:07:40  68.4M      -  75.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-16_05:22:16  68.4M      -  75.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-16_11:19:01  1.46M      -  75.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-16_11:19:21  1.39M      -  75.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-16_14:04:35  44.4M      -  75.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-16_17:03:48  43.5M      -  75.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-16_20:02:45  52.8M      -  75.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-17_00:03:51  63.9M      -  75.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-17_04:04:03  61.9M      -  75.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-17_08:03:45  48.1M      -  75.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-17_11:02:28  51.9M      -  75.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-17_14:11:25  72.1M      -  75.6G  -
rpool/data/vm-102-disk-1@rep_102_2018-08-17_17:16:03     0B      -  75.6G  -
```

How can I list only the LATEST taken snapshots for all VMs to check the latest snapshot which was taken?

Answer (score 4):

The latest taken snapshot could be obtained with this:

```
zfs list -t snapshot -o name,creation -s creation | tail -n1
```

If using capital `-S` sorts by property in descending, returning, in this case, the first taken snapshot:

```
zfs list -t snapshot -o name,creation -S creation | tail -n1
```

Comment: First command only returns one snapshot. But it must return 30 lines of results (for 30 vms) one for each latest taken snapshots.

Comment: `tail -n30` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your specific situation, because snapshots can exist on all levels of nested file systems.

If you know for certain that all descendant file systems of each VM  are snapshotted at the exact same time (with use of `zfs snapshot -r <root_filesystem>` instead of individually), then you just have to look at the root level (you can use all root filesystems or put the names in a list yourself):

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(zfs list -H -o name -d 0); do
  zfs list -H -r -d 1 -t snap -o name -S creation "${i}" | head -n1
done
```

If you have snapshots on the descendants that differ from the roots, you cannot use `-d 1` to limit the depth, but need to show all snapshots. The rest is similar:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(zfs list -H -o name -d 0); do
  zfs list -H -r -t snap -o name -S creation "${i}" | head -n1
done
```

You may also want to check if all descendant snapshots conform to the same format as the root ones, or that all descendants have snapshots. Both cases are a bit more complicated though. I suggest having a look at the `zfs list` options/man pages and using `awk` or `grep` to achieve this.